# Php Access User Data from external script

Tags: 8, users, sessions

Currently my Drupal installation is at www.example.com/wiki/

I was wondering if it is possible in Drupal 8.2.4 to access the current user uid from an external php script.

The script is located at www.example.com/someScript.php

I've tried this before

```
include_once('./includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;

if ($user->uid) {
    print "Logged in";
} else {
   print "Logged out";
}
```

Comment: The boostrap code you have is for Drupal 7. Try this one: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/bootstrap-from-external-script

Comment: @WellEndowedPenguin: you can try using Rest Services to get user login status, if that works.

Comment: @Yogesh Can I get login status based off only the drupal username/id?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about this. Checkout [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2720655) for default available Rest Services.

Comment: @WellEndowedPenguin, if you external script will be located into Drupal Root Directory, you can use the code sample provided by MrD in below ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can following file [authorize.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!authorize.php/8.2.x) to do it like this:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

function authorize_access_allowed(Request $request) {
  $account = \Drupal::service('authentication')->authenticate($request);
  if ($account) {
    \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
  }
  return Settings::get('allow_authorize_operations', TRUE) && \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer software updates');
}

try {
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
}
catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
  $response = new Response('', $e->getStatusCode());
  $response->prepare($request)->send();
  exit;
}

authorize_access_allowed($request);
$user = Drupal::currentUser();

if ($user->id()) {
    print "Logged in";
} else {
   print "Logged out";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but $user returns this when print_r `Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy Object ( [account:protected] => Drupal\Core\Session\AnonymousUserSession Object ( [uid:protected] => 0 [roles:protected] => Array ( [0] => anonymous ) [access:protected] => [name] => [preferred_langcode:protected] => [preferred_admin_langcode:protected] => [mail:protected] => [timezone:protected] => ) [initialAccountId:protected] => [_serviceId] => current_user )'

Comment: @MrD, User sessions/Details are not accessible outside of Drupal.

Comment: @MrD, There is one thing I've notice is code in authorize.php is working for authentication because the authorize.php is located inside Drupal Root directory. If we move that out of Drupal Root directory, it fails the authentication.

Comment: Well, authentication is tied to the domain, the session cookie will not work outside of it, that's correct. If it's a subdomain, then you can configure a cookie_domain in settings.php, but separate domains can not work.

Comment: The solution mentioned above worked, I placed the his code in the Drupal directory and then from my other directory I make an ajax call to the script!

Comment: So, it is necessary that the script be at the same level as Drupal Root directory? cannot be placed inside a module?