# How can I bootstrap?

Tags: 8, bootstrapping, external-scripts

How can I bootstrap Drupal 8 from an external script?

This an example script from the [RabbitMQ Work Queues tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html).

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false);
echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";
$callback = function ($msg) {
  echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->body, "\n";
  sleep(substr_count($msg->body, '.'));
  echo " [x] Done\n";
  $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
};

$channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
$channel->basic_consume('task_queue', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
  $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Within a worker script like this, I need to be able to create nodes.

How can I bootstrap Drupal 8 in this script?

[Php Access User Data from external script](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224104/php-access-user-data-from-external-script)? and [Bootstrap from external script](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/bootstrap-from-external-script) bootstraps passing a fake request to the kernel, which to me looks like a work-around.

In Drupal 7 you could do something like this, apparently.

```
// Bootstrap Drupal.
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: Have you investigated the probable usage of Drush commands? Modules like Devel generate content, users, etc.. with drush commands

Comment: Maybe do some reading up on "headless" and REST. It can be used for both the front end and backend of a site

Comment: @LittleCoding Yes, using a worker that only consumes messages from the queue and sends HTTP requests to Drupal has been considered as well. However, I am more interested to learn if this approach can work as well.

Comment: What about the opposite order? Have Drupal make an HTTP request to check the queue for new/updated messages and process them accordingly. This would be managed by the CRON system in Drupal. And a real server CRON can be setup to trigger Drupal's CRON system rather then being triggered by user visits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up inheriting the kernel and will adjust it as needed be.

Something like:

```
namespace Drupal\Core;

use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;

class DrupalCliKernel extends DrupalKernel {

  public function bootstrap() {
    static::bootEnvironment();
    $this->setSitePath('sites/default');
    Settings::initialize($this->root, 'sites/default', $this->classLoader);
    $this->boot();
  }

}
```

And then:

```
use Drupal\Core\DrupalCliKernel;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalCliKernel('prod', $autoloader);
$kernel->bootstrap();

// Drupal is bootstrapped now.
```

Not yet sure if I miss something important, but I am most likely not using this, but instead relying on using HTTP requests that the worker will use as Drupal is too coupled to the HTTP request. Just putting it out if someone come here to try to accomplish something similar and want a jump-start.