# How can I bootstrap a multi-site instance?

Tags: 8, multi-sites, bootstrapping, external-scripts

It's possible to bootstrap Drupal 8 and create a new node using [answer # 174474](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/bootstrap-from-external-script).

```
define('DRUPAL_DIR', '/usr/share/nginx/html');

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/database.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/schema.inc';

// Specify relative path to the drupal root.
$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Bootstrap drupal to different levels
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('entity.manager');

$entity = $em->getStorage('node')->create([
  'type' => "article",
  'title' => "test entity",
  'body' => "body body body",
]);
$entity->save();
```

Is it possible to bootstrap a subsite database when using [multisite](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base) to create the new node in a specific subsite?

In Drupal 7, [this can be done](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2013-09-03/drupal-bootstrap-on-multi-site-d7) by using the function drupal_override_server_variables, but this function doesn't exist in Drupal 8.

I also tried modifying the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variables [according to this forum post](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2010-01-14/drupal-bootstrap-on-multi-site), with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by setting the server variable  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] to '/subsite/index.php' (where /subsite/ is the url path to the subsite).

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/subsite/index.php';

define('DRUPAL_DIR', '/usr/share/nginx/html');
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/database.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/schema.inc';

// Specify relative path to the drupal root.
$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Bootstrap drupal to different levels
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('entity.manager');

$entity = $em->getStorage('node')->create(
array(
  'type' => "article",
  'title'=> "test entity",
  'body' => "body body body",
));

$entity->save();
```

Comment: What if we have same code base with multiple database? How to bootstrap then a specfic database?